# How can I integrate the following function in $\Bbb{R}^3$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral

> Let $A=\{(x,y,z)\in \Bbb{R}^3: y<z^2<x<1\}$. I want to check if the integral exists $$\int_A z e^{x+y}d\lambda_3(x,y,z)$$but my problem I that I don't see from where to where the indices went. I thought that $y\in (-\infty, 1)$ but thats totally wrong in the solution. But they don't gave an explication.
>
> So you don't need to compute the integral but maybe someone can help me how to find the intervalls on which we should integrate? It would help if there is something like a general way, so where should we start in such an exercise for finding the integral boundarys.

Thanks a lot this would be very nice!

Comment: There is no lower bound on $y$ given? I would go with the order $dy ~ dz ~ dx$, and the bound of  $y$ is $- \infty \leq y \leq z^2$. Can you figure out the bound of $z$ and $x$? Also note that there is symmetry about xy-plane and the integrand is an odd function wrt $z$ so the integral should be zero,

Comment: no there is no other bound given.

Comment: Sorry but why do you know where to start to integrate, so is there a trick or some procedere which works most of the time? @MathLover

Comment: @MathLover sorry I thought about the other two boundaries but I have no idea. so I thought that $\sqrt{y}\leq z\leq x$ but I don't think that this works

Comment: at least in the beginning, you should sketch the region. given this is $3D$ you can sketch $2D$ projections or take help of $3D$ online plotters like geogebra 3D. I decided to start with $y$ first as I could see that if I take the projection of the region in xz-plane, for all points, I have the same bounds of $y$.

Comment: No the bounds of $x$ and $z$ is given by $z^2 \leq x \leq 1$. How would you find area of this region in xz-plane?

Comment: ah so then $0\leq x\leq 1$ and $x\leq z\leq \sqrt{x}$?@MathLover

Comment: @aprozz Note that $\sqrt y < |z| < \sqrt x$

Comment: @MrProof is this with respect to my last comment?

Comment: $- \sqrt x \leq z \leq \sqrt x, 0 \leq x \leq 1$ or $z^2 \leq x \leq 1, -1 \leq z \leq 1$ depending on which order you choose.

Comment: ah perfect thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [Geogebra 3D](https://www.geogebra.org/classic/qzaqf6nu), you can find that

$$\bar A=B\cup C,$$
where
$$B=\{ (x, y, z): x\in [0, 1], y\in (-\infty, 0] \text{ and } z \in [-\sqrt{x}, \sqrt{x}] \}$$
and $$C=\{ (x, y, z): x\in [0, 1], y\in [0, x] \text{ and } z \in [-\sqrt{x}, -\sqrt{y}]\cup [\sqrt{y}, \sqrt{x}] \}.$$

Comment: sorry but in an exam I cant use geo gebra

Comment: Geogebra gives you a geometrical way of finding $A$ in the case that you have no idea. Of course, we don't need Geogebra to to do that!

Comment: @MathLover could you please explain why?

Comment: @MathLover Ah ok you are right!

Comment: @MathLover I fixed it, hope it works!